# jQuery showing unexpected result in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have the following file structure in codeigniter..

```
applications/...
system/...
assets/js
```

and under the js folder i have included the downloaded jQuery file and my script named a.js

In the head section i have also included their links. As below:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/a.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

my a.js contains only the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("loaded"):

});
```

But it is not showing any alert whenever I reload the page. But the same code runs fine when i do not use codeigniter.
However inline jQuery is working. For example the following code is working..

```
<p onclick="$(this).hide();" > CLICK ME AND I WILL HIDE </p>
```

What is the problem. How to fix or where I am doing wrong. Please help me....

Comment: You need to load jquery before your custom script

Comment: please explain a little @koala_dev

Comment: The order of the `<script>` tags in the `<head>` section should be reversed (jquery on top) so that jquery loads first and is available to use in your custom script

Comment: <script  type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/a.js"></script>

I did it as above but still not working...

Comment: have you checked your browser's console for any errors? (Ctrl+Shift+J)

Comment: yes friend it worked. I could fix it ... thanxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 1):

Change your header for including js

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/a.js"></script>
```